# Is there a way to start a sibling docker container mounting volumes from the host?

Tags: docker

**the scenario**: I have a host that has a running docker daemon and a working docker client and socket. I have 1 docker container that was started from the host and has a docker socket mounted within it. It also has a mounted docker client from the host. So I'm able to issue docker commands at will from whithin this docker container using the aforementioned mechanism.

**the need**: I want to start another docker container from within this docker container; in other words, I want to start a `sibling` docker container from another sibling docker container.

**the problem**: A problem arises when I want to mount files that live inside the host filesystem to the sibling container that I want to spin up from the other docker sibling container. It is a problem because when issuing `docker run`, the docker daemon mounted inside the docker container is really watching the host filesystem. So I need access to the host file system from within the docker container which is trying to start another sibling.

In other words, I need something along the lines of:

```
# running from within another docker container: 
docker run --name another_sibling \
  -v {DockerGetHostPath: path_to_host_file}:path_inside_the_sibling \
  bash -c 'some_exciting_command'
```

Is there a way to achieve that? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Paths are always on the host, it doesn't matter that you are running the client remotely (or in a container).

Remember: the docker client is just a REST client, the "-v" is always about the daemon's file system.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by saying that `paths are always on the host`. The docker container has a different file system than the host, so the paths are effectively different on both fronts.

Comment: I wan't to issue my scripts all from the docker container, but as the daemon is really running on the host, I need to expand my mountpoints to the equivalent real path of the host. Maybe I'm struggling to describe the problem.

Comment: I just want to highlight that this is great and eye-opening answer. I was struggling to build a "restart sibling container" webhook and I failed to realize that the paths are resolved on docker host, not on the client-side. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to achieve this.

1. You can always make sure that  each container  mounts the correct host directory
2. You can use --volumes-from ie :

   docker run -it --volumes-from=keen_sanderson  --entrypoint=/bin/bash debian

   --volumes-from      Mount volumes from the specified container(s)
3. You can use volumes

[image: create and managa volumes screenshot]